# Employment Contract Negotiation and Graduate School (Computer Science)

Tags: graduate-school, career-path, negotiation, contract

Is it possible to negotiate employment contracts to include sponsorship for graduate school? For example, accepting the job and school on the terms that the job will pay for Master's and I would be contractually obliged to work for the company after I get my degree?

Is this a common thing, I do not want to be in a position where my contract gets taken off of the table for asking an unreasonable thing.

(The Master's would be absolutely relevant to the engineering position at the company)

Comment: This is likely a better fit over at workplace.se.

Comment: It's possible, but inside knowledge of the employer would probably help.